# Spring MVC response output has no headers

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I set up a Java config Spring MVC web application but when I navigate to the home page, it outputs the raw page source.

For example, I expect to see

```
Hello World!
```

But I see:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<html>
    <body>Hello World!</body>
</html>
```

directly in the browser.

Looking at the response, it looks like no response headers are being sent.

Anyone know why?

```
public class WebInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext sc) throws ServletException {
        WebApplicationContext context = getContext();
        sc.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context)); // attach WebApplicationContext to ServletContext life cycle
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = sc.addServlet("DispatcherServlet", new DispatcherServlet(context));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1); // positive value means eagerly load on start up
        dispatcher.addMapping("/*"); // map DispatcherServlet to /* URL
    }

    private AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext getContext() {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        context.setConfigLocation("com.example.app.config"); // package containing @Configuration object
        return context;
    }
}

@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example.app") // base package to search for @Component / @Controller
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    // set default servlet handler.
    // equivalent to <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver getInternalResourceViewResolver() {
        final InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

        return resolver;
    }
}

@Controller
public class MainController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE)
    public String main() {
        return "index";
    }

}
```

**Edit:**

It looks like when I remove the `<%@page ...>` line from the .jsp, the HTML displays properly. But that means that this JSP is not being parsed as a JSP but instead output directly as is to the browser...?

Comment: `when I navigate to the home page, it outputs the raw page source` What do you mean?

Comment: I edited the question to clarify it.

Comment: Open your browser's network console and see what's in the response. What does your `index.jsp` contain?

Comment: If you remove the "<%@..." tag of course the page will be loaded, because it's a plain html. But that way you can't add nor use any JSP / JSTL / scripting capability.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few concepts involved here.

First, we need to see what the [Servlet Specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/) says about the order url-pattern matching

> 1. The container will try to find an **exact match** of the path of the 
>      request to the path of the servlet. A successful match selects the servlet.
> 2. The container will recursively try to **match the longest path-prefix**. 
>      This is done by stepping down the path tree a directory at a time, using
>      the ’/’ character as a  path separator. The longest match determines the 
>      servlet selected.
> 3. If the last segment in the URL path contains an extension (e.g. .jsp), 
>      the servlet  container will try to **match a servlet that handles requests 
>      for the extension**. An  extension is defined as the part of the last 
>      segment after the last ’.’ character.
> 4. If neither of the previous three rules result in a servlet match, the 
>      container will  attempt to serve content appropriate for the
>      resource requested. **If a "default"  servlet is defined for the
>      application, it will be used**. Many containers provide **an implicit
>      default servlet** for serving content.

Your `DispatcherServlet` is mapped to

```
dispatcher.addMapping("/*");
```

. It therefore declares path mapping that will be used in step 2. This `DispatcherServlet` basically handles all requests.

Let's say you send your request to

```
http://yourhost.com/context/
```

your `MainController` and its `main()` handler method will be used to handle the request. The method returns the view name `index`. Your `InternalResourceViewResolver` resolves that view name to

```
/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp
```

It will get a [`RequestDispatcher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html) for that path and [`forward`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29) to it. Because your `DispatcherServlet` is mapped to `/*`, it will be the `Servlet` chosen to handle that internal `forward`. Normally, it wouldn't have any way to handle it because you don't have a `@Controller` handler method mapped to that path. However, you do have

```
@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
}
```

which [enables](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer.html) the [`DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/resource/DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler.html) configuration.

> Enable forwarding to the "default" Servlet. When this method is used
>   the DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler will try to auto-detect the
>   "default" Servlet name. Alternatively, you can specify the name of the
>   default Servlet via enable(String).

This `DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler` is registered and used to attempt to handle any requests that weren't handled by `@Controller` instances in the `DispatcherServlet`.

So the `DispatcherServlet` is used to handle

```
/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp
```

but it has no `@Controller`, so it uses the `DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler`. This `HttpRequestHandler` finds the Servlet container's default `Servlet` and delegates handling the request to it.

Typically, Servlet containers have a default `Servlet` implementation which simply writes the content of the requested resources to the `HttpServletResponse` `OutputStream`. I am sure for Tomcat, you'd have to check for other containers.

So this default Servlet will see

```
/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp
```

then find this resource and stream it directly to the response `OutputStream`, writing JSP contents rather than the rendered HTML.

The simple solution is to map your servlet to `\`. If you do, the `RequestDispatcher` used by the `InternalResourceViewResolver` will again forward to

```
/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp
```

but that path will not be matched by the `DispatcherServlet` since it is a default Servlet (step 4). It will instead be matched by the container's `Servlet` meant for processing JSPs. Tomcat has `JspServlet` for that.

Comment: Mapping to "/" instead of "/*" does not seem to be a valid solution. After that tha app becomes unreachable.

Comment: @medve Are you having the same issue as OP? You'll have to provide more details (perhaps a new question).

Comment: Yes, I have. We've solved the problem adding web.xml as explained above.

Answer (score -1):

The solution we've came up recently is that you are forced to configure your web app (specifically DispatcherServlet) using web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>webapp.config.WebAppConfig</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

works perfectly. I know. Sad to say

```
public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
// ...
  @Override
  protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[] {"/*"};
  } // Neither with "/"
}
```

won't work.

Comment: Those two configs (if both with `/`) are equivalent. There must be something else interfering with your app.